# typescript error TS2339 when using method from another class in event handler and binding current class context

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a service which handles all of my dom manipulation called `DomService`

I have another service handling modal functionality called `ModalService`

In `ModalService` I'm binding a few events and giving it a method from `DomService` as the listener which looks like:

`document.body.addEventListener('focus', this.domService.keyPress.bind(this), true);`

and then keyPress looks something like:

```
keyPress(event){
    if (event.which === key.escape) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.hide();
    }
}
```

It works fine, the problem is typescript stills sees `this` as a reference to the `DomService` class when it's actually bound to the `ModalService` class, so it's telling me the `hide` property doesn't exist on type `DomService`

Is there anything I can do to get typescript to chill?

Comment: Which `this` is seen as a `DomService`? The one inside `keyPress` or the one in `addEventListener`? *EDIT: nevermind I see what you mean.* Also, there's always the trusty `// @ts-ignore` comment if all you're looking for is a way to silence the typescript error.

Comment: We can stop at the line `I have a service which handles all of my dom manipulation`.  Don't, we should avoid direct DOM manipulation in Angular.

Comment: Additionally, if you know that `this` will always a reference to a `ModalService`, you can inform typescript of the change in context in the method by changing the signature to: `keyPress(this: ModalService, event) { ... }` (Note that using `this` as the first argument acts as a type annotation only, it does not appear as an argument in the output).

Comment: @Alex I didn't think I needed to add a lot of detail, but the DomService mostly handles creating dynamic elements via resolveComponentFactory. You can read more about it here: https://medium.com/@caroso1222/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6

Comment: @Kolby Sure thing, I get the picture now. I instantly jumped to conclusions based on only that comment :P

Comment: @CRice that's what I was looking for. Add an answer and I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the context of `this` in any function by adding it (and its type) as the first argument to the function. So to change the context of `this` inside `keyPress` to be a `ModalService`, you would do:

```
keyPress(this: ModalService, event) {
    if (event.which === key.escape) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.hide(); // Now is OK.
    }
}
```

You can read more about that feature [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters).

In addition to that, you can always add a line `// @ts-ignore` above any line creating an error to silence it, if the above solution isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) and handle (subscribe) "emit" event.

**ModalService**

```
this.subscriptionHide = this.domService.getHideEmitter()
  .subscribe(() => this.hide());
```

**DomService**

```
hideEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

keyPress(event){
    if (event.which === key.escape) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.hideEmitter.emit(null);
    }
}

getHideEmitter() {
    return this.hideEmitter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your functions to arrow functions.

Change

```
keyPress(event) {
```

To

```
keyPress = (event) => {
```

You can read about arrow functions in typescript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-and-arrow-functions)

Comment: I want it to have the context of the ModalService though. It has a `hide` method that I need to call.