# 'thisArg' context not correctly recognized in bound function with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, this, typechecking

With the below code, TypeScript won't recognize the context of `thisArg` (which should be `a` and should have `saySomething()` method. is there another way to give context of `thisArg` for TypeScript?

The code:

```
class A {
    saySomething() {
        console.log('Hello!');
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(a: A) {
        const boundSaySomething = this.saySomethingMyself.bind(a);
        boundSaySomething();
    }

    saySomethingMyself() {
        this.saySomething();
    }
}

const test = new B(new A());
```

the console correctly logs `Hello`, but the the type checking is saying

`Property 'saySomething' does not exist on type 'B'.(2339)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49456625/1979665) solved my issue.

Basically, I had to

> change the context of this in any function by adding it (and its type)
> as the first argument to the function.

In my case, I had to change `saySomethingMyself` method from `saySomethingMyself()` to `saySomethingMyself(this: A)`.

Complete updated code:

```
class A {
    saySomething() {
        console.log('Hello!');
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(a: A) {
        const boundSaySomething = this.saySomethingMyself.bind(a);
        boundSaySomething();
    }

    saySomethingMyself(this: A) {
        (this).saySomething();
    }
}

const test = new B(new A());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too confusing for the linter, I rather would play with inheritance.
I just suggest you to cast as any , because cast as "A" type won't work :

```
saySomethingMyself() {
    (<any>this).saySomething();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. How would you play with inheritance? Why casting to `A` won't work (if you know)?

Comment: I think you can only cast the "this" context  with something related like a baseClass and  <any> is like a joker to exit the typings, not sure about that ... So if you edit B to extends A, B will have the saySomething method accessible by inheritance, and ( optionally) you will be available to cast "this" as A type instead of "any"

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the `this` type for your method.

```
saySomethingMyself(this: A) {
```

Full solution:

```
class A {
    saySomething() {
        console.log('Hello!');
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(a: A) {
        const boundSaySomething = this.saySomethingMyself.bind(a);
        boundSaySomething();
    }

    saySomethingMyself(this: A) {
        this.saySomething();
    }
}

const test = new B(new A());
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQmAngZQPYFsBTAFwAsBLAOwHMAKASkRTReF0olxEIDoRc6AcgAShEPwCEg+gG5mqAL5IlSUJBgAhJq3YRiAJwCuwYrn20wALjiNkLHR2LQARrkOUAJtix4iZKtTQALzQ-hA8GDgEJBQ0ALKYEGIAZjzOVB4WsvL2ru5ePtH+NAxyLCoskb4xAQlJIMm0YdawtjksYRGFfrF02eXKSKq6TsSEesHQlIQA7tAatNNzsAzZQA)

Comment: Yes thanks for the feedback, it's the answer I came to and that I posted.

Comment: Just one question: how did you shared the playground? Just by copying the URL?

Comment: Yes, I clicked Cmd + S (it copies the URL for you).